# Como colocar elementos de uma lista em outra lista

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
a = list()
b = list()
c = list()

a = (1,2,3)
b = (2,4,6)

c = a + b[1]

print(c)
```

Como eu faço pra adicionar um elemento de uma lista em outra lista?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use o método [`extend`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) para adicionar os itens da lista `a` e o [`append`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) para adicionar o segundo item da lista `b`:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [2, 4, 6]
c = []

c.extend(a)
c.append(b[1])

print(c)

# [1, 2, 3, 4]
```